# Interface Best Practice

Tags: java, interface, implementation

Probably a general question, but it is considered a bad practice to have an interface (**Service**), and an implementation of it (**ServiceImpl**), but with **ServiceImpl** containing *private* utility methods that are not contained in the interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not bad practice at all - I'd expect almost *any* non-trivial concrete implementation class to contain private methods. The alternative would often be to have much too large method bodies within the class.

Don't forget, no-one *outside* the class should care at all whether you've got lots of private methods or not. They should only care about your public API (or your package / protected API where relevant).

Answer (score 5):

No not at all, exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 5):

Reason for interface is that you define a contract, your implementation can have any number of private method to make that contract working.

This by no way is considered bad practice, to add to it your implementation class can also provide public methods.

In case instead of working with the API provided by interface you use the public methods of the implementation class that is definitely a bad practice on a very general note, though sometimes there are cases where it cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

No, that's fine. Your Service interface just lists things that it wants to expose to the world. How it's implemented is up to you. If those private utility methods are used to implement the interface, you're fine.